# Switch function in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement

What do I have to write in the `case`s (of `switch` function in PHP) to make `if $number > 0 && $number < 15`?

I tried with:

```
<?php
    $number = rand("0","100");
    switch($number) {
        case: $number > 0 && $number < 15;
            $output = 1;
            break;
        case: $number > 15 && $number < 50;
            $output = 2;
            break;
    }
    return $output;
?>
```

Comment: It's unusual to use switches for use cases like this - it works anyway

Comment: You should use `mt_rand(0, 100)` instead of `rand()`.

Comment: What happens if the number is 15? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following. Your colons were in the wrong place!

```
<?php
  $number = rand("0", "100");
  switch(true) {
    case $number > 0 && $number < 15:
      $output = 1;
      break;
    case $number > 15 && $number < 50:
      $output = 2;
      break;
  }
?>
```

From the comment by DaveRandom below. Be aware that nothing will happen if $number is equal to 15. I would recommend changing one of your `switch` statements. Perhaps by changing your first case into:

```
   case $number > 0 && $number <= 15:
```

Comment: -1, it's not `switch($number)` but `switch(true)` because the cases are boolean assertions.

Comment: ...and what happens when `$number == 15` ? ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom Touche ;) Ill mention this in my answer :)